# tomcat received data Listener

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using an application which send data to my local tomcat server.

So my question is, how to handle data received in tomcat with java ?

can some one give me an exemple how to use Listener.

Comment: How is it sending data to your tomcat server?? HTTP request?

Comment: i recived data from an android application (funf journal).so HTTP request.

Comment: Write a servlet that implements a `doGet` or `doPost` method (depending on whether the data is received with an HTTP GET or POST request) and deploy it on Tomcat.

Comment: What is not clear for me is how can i get this data.tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a Java web application and deploy it to your tomcat server.

The web application will need to handle whatever request is being sent to Tomcat.

Do some reading:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp.html

Comment: If the application send a file (.txt) to my tomcat, can i use a servlet to parse it?

Comment: Yes you can. The request will need to be the correct format and the servlet will need to explicitly handle it. This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet

Comment: I am not uploading a file! i send it to my localhost http::/125.28.28.3:8080 from my phone. so how tomcat will "understand" that this file is for my appweb1?

Comment: If you are sending a txt file you are uploading it ;). You will need to send the file to something like: http::/125.28.28.3:8080/my-app and then mount a web application on /my-app to handle the text file.

Comment: thx, can you give me an exemple. I am not obliged to use a listener because i recive a file evry 20sec?

Comment: You will need to look into web apps. Its too big to simply give an example